# I get an Exception when I try to open a side menu

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to develop a side menu with a sliding home screen.

This is what I did.

set hideLeftSideMenuBool to true in constants and using menuBtn to openSideMenu,

I get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar.showOnTopSidemenuImpl(Toolbar.java:1616)
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar$12.run(Toolbar.java:1567)
at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.flushAnimation(AnimationManager.java:220)
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar.showOnTopSidemenu(Toolbar.java:1563)
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar.openSideMenu(Toolbar.java:343)
..................

Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
        hi.setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true);
        
        Toolbar tb = new Toolbar(false);        
        final Container ToolbarCnt = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        Container menuCnt = new Container(new FlowLayout(CENTER, CENTER));
        Button menuBtn = new Button(theme.getImage("ToolbarSideMenuIcon.png"),"Container");
        menuCnt.add(menuBtn);
        ToolbarCnt.add(BorderLayout.WEST, menuCnt);
        ToolbarCnt.getAllStyles().setMarginUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE);
        ToolbarCnt.getAllStyles().setMargin(1, 1, 2, 2);
        
        Command MenuCommand = new Command("");       
        Button HomeCommand= new Button("Home");
        HomeCommand.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xA6A6A6);
        HomeCommand.addActionListener((evt) -> {
            SideMenuBar.closeCurrentMenu();
        });    
        
        Container cnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        cnt.add(HomeCommand);

        hi.setToolbar(tb);
        tb.setTitleCentered(false);
        tb.setTitleComponent(ToolbarCnt);
        MenuCommand.putClientProperty("SideComponent", cnt);
        hi.addCommand(MenuCommand);
        menuBtn.addActionListener((evt) -> {

                hi.getToolbar().openSideMenu();                
            

        });
```

Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 0):

The menu is constructed when things are added to it and since you didn't add anything into the menu it was never constructed. Just add items to the menu e.g.:

```
tb.addMaterialCommandToLeftSideMenu("Hello", materialIcon, e -> {});
```